# OLE Automation - Ghost Excel Instance in Task Manager

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, ole

I am using `wxAutomationObject` to export data to MS Excel. I have created a few helper classes ExcelApp, ExcelWorkbook etc... all of which inherits from `wxAutomationObject`.

Briefly, ExcelApp is as follows:

```
class ExcelApp :public wxAutomationObject
{

    public:

        ExcelApp(WXIDISPATCH* dispatchPtr = NULL);

        ~ExcelApp() = default;

        
        void Quit();

        std::unique_ptr<ExcelWorkbook> CreateWorkbook(bool Visible = true);

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ExcelWorkbook>> GetOpenedWorkbooks();

        long GetNumberofOpenedWorkbooks() const;


    private:
        wxAutomationObject m_App;   
};
```

The constructor is implemented as follows:

```
ExcelApp::ExcelApp(WXIDISPATCH* dispatchPtr):wxAutomationObject(dispatchPtr)
{
        if (!m_App.GetInstance("Excel.Application"))
            throw std::exception("An instance of Excel object could not be created.");
}
```

And to create a workbook, I used to following code:

```
std::unique_ptr<ExcelWorkbook> ExcelApp::CreateWorkbook(bool Visible)
{
        auto wb = std::make_unique<ExcelWorkbook>();

        bool suc = m_App.GetObject(*wb, "Workbooks.Add");

        if (!suc)
            return nullptr;


        if (Visible)
            m_App.PutProperty("Visible", true);

        
        return std::move(wb);
}
```

This whole OLE implementation is part of a dynamic menu. Part of the code for the event handler for menu is:

```
void MyFrame::OnExportToExcelButtonHandler(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    
        auto item = static_cast<wxMenu*>(event.GetEventObject());

        std::unique_ptr<ExcelWorkbook> xlsWB ((ExcelWorkbook*)event.GetEventUserData());

        
        bool CreateNewWB = false;
    
        try
        {
            

            //Export either the entire workbook or the active worksheet to a new Workbook
            if (xlsWB == nullptr)
            {
                auto xlsApp = ExcelApp(); 

                xlsWB = std::move(xlsApp.CreateWorkbook());

                CreateNewWB = true;
            }
```

In terms of exporting data and formatting, everything works fine. However, after closing the created Workbooks *Excel.exe still remains* in the taskbar list. I wonder what I could be missing?

By the way, I tried the very basic sample shipped with wxWidgets and there seems to remain no ghost instances of Excel after quitting. I

I am using wxWidgets 3.1.4 on Windows 10 using VS 2019.

**EDIT 1:**

The ribbon button that generates the dynamic menu:

```
void MyFrame::OnExportToExcelButtonClicked(wxRibbonButtonBarEvent& event)
{
    auto excel = sys::win32::ole::ExcelApp();


        auto PrepareMenu = [&](wxMenu* Menu)
        {

            try
            {
                

                wxMenuItem* item1 = Menu->Append(wxID_ANY, "New Excel Workbook");
                item1->SetBitmap(wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_NEW));

                Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &MyFrame::OnExportToExcelButtonHandler, this, item1->GetId());


                auto wbs = excel.GetOpenedWorkbooks();

                if (wbs.size() > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < wbs.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        auto ExcelWB = std::move(wbs[i]);

                        wxMenuItem* item1 = Menu->Append(wxID_ANY, ExcelWB->GetFullName());

                        Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &MyFrame::OnExportToExcelButtonHandler, this, item1->GetId(), wxID_ANY, ExcelWB.release());

                        
                    }
                }

            }
}
```

The problem seems to originate from the following line:

```
Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &MyFrame::OnExportToExcelButtonHandler, this, item1->GetId(), wxID_ANY, ExcelWB.release());
```

The `ExcelWB` pointer is now owned by the wxWidgets system and therefore a reference remains and thus the ghost Excel.exe remains.

To solve it, in the following procedure I added:

```
void MyFrame::OnExportToExcelButtonHandler(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Unbind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &MyFrame::OnExportToExcelButtonHandler, this, event.GetId(), wxID_ANY, xlsWB.get());
```

But the problem still remains. I am not sure how to properly get rid of the pointer that is now owned by the menu. I redesigned some parts with shared_ptr and it did not help.

Comment: No Quit() call.  Hard to do when xlsApp is a local variable.

Comment: I tried it manually with "Application.Quit" and the ghost instance still remains. The problem is when xlsApp is created and destroyed everything is fine; however, as soon as I call `xlsApp.CreateWorkbook` then the ghost instance remains.

Comment: @macroland, so how is the sample closing everything? What do you do differently? Can you make the sample leave that ghost instance with the minimal changes? One other idea - try to get rid of smart pointers and use plain old ones.

Comment: @Igor, the sample is very basic, just creates an instance of wxAutomationObject and only works with a single object and executes only a few commands. Initially I used raw pointers and the problem exists with that approach too. I read in one post that if there is a reference remains somewhere then Excel instance is not terminated. To get rid of that unknown "reference", I switched to smart pointers.

Comment: Is there a technical reason you can't mix ATL and wx? I'd use ATL smart pointers to manage COM objects. You could do the wx for the UI I guess. For sure, I'd make a test where all you do is create the Workbook and don't manipulate it any way by adding content or stuff. Before you call Quit() on the Application, I'd try calling Close() on the workbook.

Comment: I havent tried mixing ATL and wx, so not sure if it is technically doable and the last time I used ATL was long time ago (I guess it was with Visual C++ 6.0). I remember doing a similar test, just created one workbook (after `xlsWB = std::move(xlsApp.CreateWorkbook());` added a `return` statement) and closed the workbook manually and the ghost Excel.exe was still there. The only thing that I am not so sure is if `std::unique_ptr<ExcelWorkbook> xlsWB ((ExcelWorkbook*)event.GetEventUserData());` is keeping a reference which is preventing the Excel instance to be terminated.

Comment: a side note: don't do return std::move(wb); let RVO do its magic instead.

Answer (score 0):

You already may be doing that but just to be sure.

When debugging such things, make sure the application instance is always visible so you can see when it for example gets stuck waiting on a user input, e.g., asking to save a modified workbook, preventing it from quitting.

I have written wxWidgets-based MS Excel automation wrapper [wxAutoExcel](https://github.com/PBfordev/wxAutoExcel) (it uses a shared instead of unique pointer for Excel objects) and I have never encountered application ghosts, except when I terminated my application when debugging, without disposing Excel objects.

BTW, I do not get why your `ExcelApp` both derives from `wxAutomationObject` and has `wxAutomationObject` as a member variable (`m_App`). What is the `IDispatch` used in the `ExcelApp` ctor for?

Comment: I have added more info, please see my edit regarding the problem.

Comment: Regarding your questions: if I dont use `m_App` then the program crashes. However, you are right, if I use `m_App` I dont have to derive it from `wxAutomationObject`. Frankly, `IDispatch` is not used for anything at the moment except passing to `wxAutomationObject`'s constructor in the inheritance chain.

Comment: Sorry, I am not really up-to-date even with a decade old C++11 and all that move semantics makes me queasy. For example, `wxAutomationObject` does not seem to support move directly, as wxWidgets does not use Modern C++. However, when you move it, is its dtor called? This calls `Release()` on its `IDispatch`, and the ctor never calls `AddRef()`... But that would actually result in objects prematurely released and not left over?

Comment: I am also quite surprised you can call `wxAutomation::GetObject()` not only on property but with a method ("Workbooks.Add")?! Sorry, I do not have an answer to the question about the event object. And its my first time using StackOverflow's comments and I find it pretty limiting, so I'd rather not write any more here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it seems like I solved the issue, using the following steps:

1. Instead of a *menu*, now a *dialog* is used; therefore, the menu does not own the pointer anymore.
2. All `wxAutomationObject` inheriting objects are passed around via std::unique_ptr.